# align UILabel to be centered on UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am implementing a footer view, which is a UIView and it has a label inside it. I wanted it so that the UILabel stays in the center all the time, but it just won't. Here's my code:

```
- (void)setupFooterView
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView_.frameWidth, kFooterViewHeight)];
    [footerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *loadMoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [loadMoreLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loadMoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNova size:16]];
    [loadMoreLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [loadMoreLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    CGSize desiredSize =  [[PNRConstants kLoadingMore] sizeWithFont:loadMoreLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(footerView.frameWidth, footerView.frameHeight) lineBreakMode:loadMoreLabel.lineBreakMode];
    [loadMoreLabel setFrameSize:desiredSize];
    [loadMoreLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(footerView.frameWidth/2, footerView.frameHeight/2)];
    self.loadingMoreLabel_ = loadMoreLabel;
    [footerView addSubview:self.loadingMoreLabel_];
    [loadMoreLabel release];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [spinner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [spinner setFrameX:self.loadingMoreLabel_.frameX - spinner.frameWidth - 10];
    [spinner setFrameY:self.loadingMoreLabel_.frameY];
    self.spinner_ = spinner;
    [footerView addSubview:self.spinner_];
    [spinner release]; 

    [self.scrollView_ setFooterView_:footerView];
    [footerView release];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[loadMoreLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(footerView.frameWidth/2, footerView.frameHeight/2)];
```

The footerView.frameWidth/2 needs to be

```
footerView.frameWidth/2 - loadMoreLabel.frame.size.width/2
```

This is because the anchor of the label is in the top left corner instead of in the center.  You subtract half the width of your label to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

after setting label's frame: `[yourLabel setCenter: yourFooter.center];`

Comment: ... and of course your footer's frame must be already set ( and added to it's superview ) by the time you set label's center.

Comment: no, you are defining the frame like [loadMoreLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(footerView.frameWidth/2, footerView.frameHeight/2)]; instead of jus saying: [loadMoreLabel setCenter:footerView.center]; It is not always the same.

Comment: do not init the footer with frame. firts just init, then set the frame, then add to self.view (or whatever view), and only after doing that, set the frame of the label and it's center. by the way CHECK FOOTER's FRAME after adding it.

Comment: but if I set the autoresize mask of the footer view when the superview changes, won't that also auto-resize the subviews?

Comment: Won't work, footer.center is in footer's superview coordinates, which will likely place the view completely off screen.

Answer (score 0):

The right way: use nibs, set the resize mask and call it a day.

The painful way: programmatically create the label.
Then a couple of options:
- make the label as wide as the footer and set it's text align to center.
- set the label's center property to footer.frame.width/2 and footer.frame.height/2

Edit: oh, you're dong that already. Set the text align property of yournlabel to center.